# Macro works in step by step but not in F5 mode

Tags: excel, vba

I have many shapes to copy paste from an Excel file to a PowerPoint presentation (10 slides). When I execute the macro using F8, it works, but if I execute it directly (using button or the play button - triangle-) it doesn't paste all. For example 1 shape in 1st slide ok. second slide nothing, 3rd slide half of shapes only... and not respecting the position I gave in the macro. What I can see, is, when it is running faster (by run) it is not giving time for every step to be executed until the end, so its executing a part of code and not other parts.

PS: I do not have any error in the end.

I tried DoEvents, but nothing changed.

```
Sub copierppt()
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PptDoc As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim NbShpe As Byte
Dim i As Integer

Set PPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True 'l'application sera visible
Set PptDoc = PPT.Presentations.Open("D:\Users\MATRIX.pptx")

    '5 ###################  slide 5 ####################
    PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=5
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("names").ChartObjects("names graphe1").Copy
    PPT.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
    PPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    NbShpe = PptDoc.Slides(5).Shapes.Count
    With PptDoc.Slides(5).Shapes(NbShpe)
        .Name = "names graphe1"
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 230
        .Height = 270
        '.Width = 350
    End With
    DoEvents

    ' 6 ###################  slides 6 ####################
    PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=6
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("surmane").ChartObjects("surname graphe1").Copy
    PPT.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
    PPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    NbShpe = PptDoc.Slides(6).Shapes.Count
    With PptDoc.Slides(6).Shapes(NbShpe)
        .Name = "Open surname graphe1"
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 230
        .Height = 270
        '.Width = 350
    End With

    ' 7 ################### slide 7 ####################
    PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=7
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("adress").ChartObjects("adress graphe1").Copy
    PPT.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
    PPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    DoEvents
    NbShpe = PptDoc.Slides(7).Shapes.Count
    With PptDoc.Slides(7).Shapes(NbShpe)
        .Name = "adress graphe1"
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 230
        .Height = 270
        '.Width = 350
    End With

    ' 8 ################### slide 8 ####################
    PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=8
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut").ChartObjects("statut graphe1").Copy
    PPT.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
    PPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    NbShpe = PptDoc.Slides(8).Shapes.Count
    With PptDoc.Slides(8).Shapes(NbShpe)
        .Name = "statut graphe1"
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 240
        .Height = 300
        '.Width = 350
    End With

    Sheets("statut").Activate
    Sheets("statut").Range("G21").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    PPT.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

    PPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    NbShpe = PptDoc.Slides(8).Shapes.Count

    With PptDoc.Slides(8).Shapes(NbShpe)
        .Name = "TCD1"
        .Left = 88
        .Top = 205
        '.Height = 520
        '.Width = 20
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this a long time ago.  I think the solution was to restart the machine and the F5 key fired the code just fine.

Comment: Hello, the machine was restarted severals times but nothing change.the F5 execute the macro so so fast and not executing all the code !!

Answer (score 0):

I found in another forum this code which i adapted it regarding my needing

fin = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < fin
DoEvents
Loop

its giving sometimes the expected result, but 1/7 times not giving expected result. but i needed put it in every step, and change the value after timer +1 or +0.1, 0.5 ...

```
enter code here
Sub copierppt()
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PptDoc As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim NbShpe As Byte
Dim i As Integer

Set PPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True 'l'application sera visible
Set PptDoc = PPT.Presentations.Open("D:\Users\MATRIX.pptx")
'5 ###################  slide 5 ####################
PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=5
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("names").ChartObjects("names graphe1").Copy
PPT.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
PPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")

fin = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < fin
DoEvents
Loop
NbShpe = PptDoc.Slides(5).Shapes.Count
With PptDoc.Slides(5).Shapes(NbShpe)

fin = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < fin
DoEvents
Loop
    .Name = "names graphe1"
    .Left = 50
    .Top = 230
    .Height = 270
    '.Width = 350
fin = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < fin
DoEvents
Loop
End With
DoEvents
' 6 ###################  slides 6 ####################
PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide Index:=6
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("surmane").ChartObjects("surname graphe1").Copy
PPT.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
PPT.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
fin = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < fin
DoEvents
Loop
NbShpe = PptDoc.Slides(6).Shapes.Count
With PptDoc.Slides(6).Shapes(NbShpe)
    .Name = "Open surname graphe1"
    .Left = 50
    .Top = 230
    .Height = 270
    '.Width = 350
fin = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < fin
DoEvents
Loop
End With
'
'
'
' the same in every step for all the code
End Sub
```

Comment: could somone please help me please?